# Hook the resolution of assemblies and types loaded in a Xaml context

Tags: wpf, xaml, assemblies

for a good reason we are **prefixing** our assemblies, with a **prefix specific to each application** :

e.g. if we have a project named "A" which is a dependency of an application named "MyApplication1" the latest will use a "MA1.A" assembly generated at build-time;

if another application "MyApplication2" has also a dependency on "A" we will transform the output of "A" as "MA2.A" when building the application...

So far so good.

Now we are starting to use **WPF** and we need to **reference some types of "A" in the Xaml** :

```
xmlns:a="clr-namespace:Some.Name.Space;assembly=A"
```

This is fine at design-time but at runtime there is no more "A" assembly but a "MA1.A" or "MA2.A" assembly,
so the application crashes.

**Do you have any idea to workaround this issue without affecting too deeply the development process ?**

E.g. loading the Xaml by hand and setting the prefix is not an acceptable solution.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: Why SO has removed my first line "Hello," ? I can't even edit it ? What's wrong now with salutations ? :)

Comment: SO is not a forum, it is a Q & A site. We try to keep the questions and answers clean and sometimes add fun and pleasantries in comments.

Comment: The 'assembly' tag is for low level programming, not .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET run-time needs to know what assemblies your assembly depends on. That is why you refer to the assemblies in code so the run-time knows where to find the class(es).

If you decide to rename the classes you will have to inform the CLR of the rename action.

The only way I see is by editing the source code or [redirecting at run-time but WPF doesn't like that](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010120402/http://szymonrozga.net/blog/2009/10/redirection-to-an-assembly-with-a-different-name-and-why-it-might-not-work-in-wpf/)

> for a good reason we are prefixing our assemblies

As much as I would like to believe you; I strongly suggest that you keep the names at compile time equal to the run-time version. It will be much easier to debug and trace errors. But as you didn't mention the reason I might be wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "good reason" is that we are developing Excel addins and that these addins are all loaded in the same app-domain (at least with Excel 2003). So if "MyAddin1" and "MyAddin2" are loaded together in the same Excel instance, and they both depend on a third "A" assembly some nice things happen ;)

Comment: @Serious - Can't you name them correctly from the start so you refer to the correct names in XAML?

Comment: Sadly we can't because the prefix is not known until build time.
So when we build "MyAddin1" this will trigger the build of "A" which will be outputted as "MA1.A";
on the other hand if we build "MyAddin2" we will generate an "MA2.A" assembly.
This way if "MyAddin1" and "MyAddin2" are loaded in the same app-domain there will be no conflict.
The solution would be to transform the Xaml at build-time using temporary Xaml files with the right prefix like you say;
but now the question is how to do this cleanly with VS without messing up the build process.

Comment: @Serious - As long as it are only the XAML files that should be modified, you could create/generate an XSLT that transforms all XAML files in the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this looks quite hard to implement, because the generations/transformations should be triggered at each build taking into account the current prefix. So I guess it might require a custom MSBuild task which is not worthwhile!

Comment: @Serious - I can't really decide whether or not this is hard. The XSLT will be quite simple, what might be hard it collecting the correct names/substitutions. Running an XSLT for all XAMLs is not that hard it is just another pre-build step.

Comment: Yes but then this will create a bunch of generated Xaml files that should be included in the WPF build process, replacing the original ones; this is the tricky part.

Comment: @Serious - Modifying files during the build isn't that hard. We do it all the time (adding version numbers, generating files etc.)